# Simple ticketing simulator , Why am I able to issue tickets only in the order?

Tags: java, linked-list

I`m just learning to code and I was trying to implement a simple Ticketing Simulation .

I have Seats class , in this class I have a LinkedList storing all the seats in the saloon . I created and numbered the seats , and added them to this static LinkedList .When I`m ticketing a seat , it is done by entering a seat number and a char for its row .. I have 50 seats , every 10 seats has an alphabetic value of char . 1-10 A , 11-20 B and so on..

```
public class Seats {

public static LinkedList<Seats> seatsInSaloon;
private final int seatNumber;
private final char seatChar;

public Seats(int seatNumber, char seatChar) {

    this.seatChar = seatChar;
    this.seatNumber = seatNumber;
}

private static void generateSeats() {

    seatsInSaloon = new LinkedList<Seats>();
    char x = 'a';
    for (int i = 1; i < 51; i++) {
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
            Seats seats = new Seats(i, x);
            seatsInSaloon.add(seats);
            x++;

        } else {
            Seats seats = new Seats(i, x);
            seatsInSaloon.add(seats);
        }

    }

}

public int getSeatNumber() {
    return seatNumber;
}

public char getSeatChar() {
    return seatChar;
}

public static void fillSeats() {
    generateSeats();
}
```

}

I wanted to make sure the ticketed seat is removed from that static LinkedList holding all seats , so it cannot be booked again . While I was testing my code , I realized , if I do not issue tickets in order ( first ticket for seat 1,a.. second ticket for 2,a .. and so on..) , it acts as if that seat with given seat number and char is not existent in the static linkedlist which holds all the seats .. Can somebody help me see what I`m doing wrong ? Does it require ticketing in order because I`m using a linkedList ? Thank you..

```
    public class Ticketing {

private static Seats seats;

public static LinkedList<Seats> seeAllSeatsAvailable() {
    return Seats.seatsInSaloon;
}

public static void ticketSeat(int seatNum, char seatChar) {
    if ((seatNum > 50 || seatNum < 1) || (seatChar > 'e' || seatChar < 'a')) {
        System.out.println("please check the numbers you have entered .... ");
    }

    for (Seats s : Seats.seatsInSaloon) {
        if (s.getSeatChar() == seatChar && s.getSeatNumber() == seatNum) {
            System.out.println("HERE IS YOUR TICKET : " + seatChar + seatNum);
            Seats.seatsInSaloon.remove(s);
            break;
        } else if (!Seats.seatsInSaloon.contains(s.getSeatChar() == seatChar && s.getSeatNumber() == seatNum)) {
            System.out.println("sorry... This ticket has already been issued");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

here is the test..
public class TicketDriver {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // System.out.println(Ticketing.seeAllSeats());
    Seats.fillSeats();

    Ticketing.ticketSeat(1, 'a'); //fine



    Ticketing.ticketSeat(2, 'a'); //fine
    Ticketing.ticketSeat(3, 'a'); //fine
    Ticketing.ticketSeat(4, 'a'); //fine
    Ticketing.ticketSeat(4, 'a'); //fine , prints the correct error.

    Ticketing.ticketSeat(11, 'b'); //?????
    
    /*
    
    Last one Gives error as if this seat does not exist inside linkedlist.
    It prints "sirry,, This ticket has already been issued"
                    
    */
    

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList.contains() takes an object as it's param to test if the LinkedList contains that object. Instead of

```
} else if (!Seats.seatsInSaloon.contains(s.getSeatChar() == seatChar && s.getSeatNumber() == seatNum)) {
    System.out.println("sorry... This ticket has already been issued");
    break;
}
```

You need to pass an instance of Seats with the seatChar and seatNumber that you're looking for.

It would also make more sense if you have a class called Seat which represents one instance of a seat, and then you can define a Collection of Seat like

```
LinkedList<Seat> seats;
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Makes sense to go in that direction..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if else condition from yout ticketing class and create an another validation method for that functionality.You can copy the list you created, delete it every time you create a ticket, and perform the validation process from there..

Delete this condition.

```
else if (!Seats.seatsInSaloon.contains(s.getSeatChar() == seatChar && s.getSeatNumber() == seatNum)) {
        System.out.println("sorry... This ticket has already been issued");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense ! Thank you very much Yaser , this helps a ton !